# How to access a string from one method to another in one controller?

Tags: grails

If we have one controller, let's call it document, that has two methods, one that uploads file and another that shows the uploaded file. 
I would like to define a new string in the upload method that checks the size of the file and store a specific type name inside that string.

However I would like to access that string in another method which is the list method to be able to show it.

Here is my code:

```
Class DocumentController {

    def list() {
        //Here I would like to access that String to show it on the page

        [fileSizeType: fileSizeType]
    }

    def upload {
        //define the new String variable
        String fileSizeType = ""

        if(fileSize < 1000) {
            fileSizeType = "type1.."
        } else {
            fileSizeType = "type2.."
        }

    }
}
```

In the gsp page I would like to access the string this way:

```
<td><g:link>\${fileSizeType}</g:link></td>
```

I am getting this error when I try the code above:

```
No such property: fileSizeType for class: file_down.DocumentController
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect to the list action while passing your argument in the params.

```
def upload() {
  // simplify with ternary expression
  def fileSizeType = (fileSize < 1000) ? "type1.." : "type2.."

  redirect action:'list', params:[fileSizeType: fileSizeType]
}

// in your list action
def list() {
  [fileSizeType: params.fileSizeType]
}
```